# NullPointerException - tratamiento de excepciones

Tags: java, excepciones

Tenía el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Se genera ese error al generar un archivo PDF que ya está abierto, si está cerrado lo crea pero si está abierto salta esa excepción. Debería ser controlada.

Mi pregunta es:
¿Un `try` puede englobar dos `catch`? ¿Pueden estar dos excepciones dentro de un catch?

**Código**:

```
private void button_listaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        try {
            ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = Conexiones.listado_clientes();
            PDF_Clientes.crearPDF(clientes);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PDF generado correctamente en directorio actual.");
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al crear el PDF.");
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, npe);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El fichero está abierto. Debe cerrarlo.");
        }
    }
```

**¿Cómo debería ser controlado? ¿Está bien la solución?**

Me funcionan los mensajes de JOptionPane pero me sale en la consola / Output el siguiente error:

```
GRAVE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Aunque el código es correcto, controlar una excepción mediante un catch sólo debería hacerse si es inevitable. En el caso del NPE, normalmente deberías saber que código tiene un riesgo de lanzarla y comprobar si la expresión es null o no con un if.

Answer (score 5):

**Si** , es posible y lo puedes realizar de las siguientes maneras :

1. > ```
   > catch (IOException ex) {
   >      logger.log(ex);
   >      throw ex;
   > catch (SQLException ex) {
   >      logger.log(ex);
   >      throw ex;
   > }
   > ```
2. Válido a partir de java 7

   > ```
   > catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
   >         logger.log(ex);
   >         throw ex;
   >     }
   > ```

Link de referencia para más información [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Comment: Gracias cjara, acabo de modificar la pregunta con mi respuesta, pero no sé si es correcta mi sintaxis o lógica.

Comment: Me parece correcta. Lo que me parece un poco raro es que lance un NullPointerException si ya existe el archivo. Saludos

Comment: Aún me sale el error... El funcionamiento es correcto pero no es correcto al 100% debido a que salta el error.

Comment: Se debería indicar que la segunda opción es válida sólo a partir de Java 7.

Comment: ¿Por qué motivo me sale aún el error de la excepción? Uso Java 8.

Comment: ¿Tú catch no captura el error?

Comment: No. Me muestra el mensaje del JOptionPane como que si lo captura pero en OUTPUT me sale el error de la excepción.

Comment: Es posible que té aparezca en el outpu debido a que lo estás imprimiendo con  Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a las respuestas que ya te dieron, continua saliendo en la consola el error debido a que tienes un

```
Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Si dejas solo el JOptionPane evitarás el error en consola.